git pull changes from another checked out branch with same head

I have base branch feature-MVP-27.0/develop

Developer A  , checks out a branch from it, feature-MVP-27.0/feature-A

Developer B  , checks out a branch from it, feature-MVP-27.0/feature-B This is  is developed, and merged back into feature-MVP-27.0/develop

How does Developer A, pull the latest changes of feature-MVP-27.0/feature-B into his branch?



git pull origin feature-MVP-27.0/develop should be the straightforward way

Since developer B has already pushed his branch to the main, then all developer A has to do is pull from the main into his branch.

In other words,

Developer A checks out a branch from feature-MVP-27.0/develop
Developer B checks out a different branch from feature-MVP-27.0/develop
Developer B merges his changes into feature-MVP-27.0/develop
Developer A (while currently on branch) `git pull origin feature-MVP-27.0/develop

